# Is there an easier way of coloring terminal text using curses?

Tags: c++, terminal, colors, curses

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu in the terminal with `curses` but noticed ANSI codes don't work and that you should use `attron()` and `attroff()` in combination with `init_pair` instead. But that colors the whole string, and I only want a small part. Do I have to print out each part separately to get the colors right or is there a better way?

```cpp
// Currently using this (does not work with curses, will just display the ANSI text like normal)
printw("%s (\033[1;37m%d\033[0m): \n", message.c_str(), defaultValue.c_str());

// Instead, they use this:
init_pair(1, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);

attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
printw("Green text");
attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));

// Now how would I do my text? This looks too lengthy and will become very cluttered later on
init_pair(/* ... */);
init_pair(/* ... */);

attron(/* ... */);
printw("%s (", message.c_str());
attroff(/* ... */);
attron(/* ... */);
printw("%d", defaultValue.c_str());
attroff(/* ... */);
attron(/* ... */);
printw("): \n");
```

Comment: Little helper functions (where you can give color and text as arguments)?

Comment: With curses, that's done using attributed chars/strings (see related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76084417/does-python-curses-have-an-equivalent-to-chtype-strings/76087076#76087076)), but printw only works for plain strings.